# Navigate To Component in Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, aura

I am using one main lightning component and all other components are opening within the main components. I want to update the browser URL when the user navigates.
I am trying to navigate to a component in the community to update the URL. But it's not working.
I used below code:

```
 var pageReference = {   
        "type": "standard__component",
        "attributes": {
            "componentName": "c__Target"    
        },    

    };
    navService.generateUrl(pageReference)
    .then($A.getCallback(function(url) {
        cmp.set("v.url", url ? url : defaultUrl);
    }), $A.getCallback(function(error) {
        cmp.set("v.url", defaultUrl);
    }));
```

In the community it gives null value in url but in salesforce lightning its working fine.

I have also tried this but it didn't https://rajvakati.com/2018/11/13/navigate-to-component-using-lightningnavigation/

Comment: @salesforce-sas edited the question. Do you know ans to it

Comment: go to the marked duplicate question and check - in community only `comm__namedPage` type pageReference works. Please read the answer carefully [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/271158/70823)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use comm__namedPage instead of standard__

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm

> In Communities, the value for pageName is the URL value for a supported page. For instance, the default URL value for the Account Management page is /account-management, so the value for pageName would be account-management.
>
> The value of home is reserved for the landing page of any community in your org.
>
> However, because pages in communities are different than pages in Lightning Experience, we’ve moved them to their own namespace for better management and clarity. standard__namedPage is deprecated in communities. Use comm__namedPage instead.

```
{
type: "comm__namedPage",
attributes: {
    pageName: "home"
}
```